# Efficient way to Find most similar List<String>

Tags: java, vector, similarity, knn

I have a `list1<String>` and other 1000 `list<String>`. I need to choose the list with the most exact match values.

Today I go over each `list<String>` and compare to list1 , save the coverge in some sortedlist and in the end choose the most similar list.

```
public static <T> List<T> intersection(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

        for (T t : list1) {
            if(list2.contains(t)) {
                list.add(t);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

This operation to go over all the 1000 unique lists is taken lost of time assuming I have lots of lists to compare it too.

Could you please suggest me an efficient way / algorithm to do it?

Comment: Your `list2.contains(t)` will give you O(n*m) complexity. Maybe you could choose a faster containment check given the size of the lists is also height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lists are not sorted, so any `contains()` operation needs to search the whole list (or until found so N/2 on average).
So first sort (`Collections.sort()`) all lists, then use `Collections.binarySearch()` to find whether the String is contained or not. This needs then only (log N) instead of N/2 as before.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted anwser is good, but can still be improved. You can simply use a `LinkedHashSet`, which will take O(n) to dump data into the set, and O(1) for each contains operation. This will help if your list is big, but for small ones,  use the sort instead.

If you have duplicate entries in your list, you may got some unexpected result, as your original code will create more than one in the result. In that case, use something like Google Guava's `LinkedHashMultiset`. If you don't have Guava on your classpath, likely you will have to write one on your own if you want O(1) search time.

Just as a side note, the `Collections.sort()` will alter the original list. If you need the original order later or the list is somehow unmodifiable , you should create a copy of it, in which case i think you should try the set instead, because they take same amount of time to build, and `HashSet` use less time to perform a `contains`